# generate tuple of search results including null data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here I have a pandas dataframe structure of data, now I have a list of criteria values,like [1,2,3,4,5]. I want to extract the correspondent value in the format of tuple or list by searching the dataframe on the criteria list.

For example, if I want to have Sim == 'a' and No in [1,2,3,4,5], it will return value: (1,2,3,4,5). But if I want to have Sim == 'b' and No in [1,2,3,4,5], because there is no value on (No == 4) & (Sim == 'b'), it will return [7,8,9,'',10] or [7,8,9,nan,10].

Is there any efficient way of doing this? Many Thanks

```
>>> df
     No Sim  Value
0    0   a      0
1    1   a      1
2    2   a      2
3    3   a      3
4    4   a      4
5    5   a      5
6    0   b      6
7    1   b      7
8    2   b      8
9    3   b      9
10   5   b     10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can create `MultiIndex` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by another `Multiindex` created [`from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
def get_tuple(df, no, sim):
    df1 = df.set_index(['No','Sim']).sort_index()
    return tuple(df1['Value'].reindex(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([no,[sim]])).tolist())


print (get_tuple(df, [1,2,3,4,5], 'a'))
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

print (get_tuple(df, [1,2,3,4,5], 'b'))
(7.0, 8.0, 9.0, nan, 10.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tuple(df.set_index(
        ['No', 'Sim']
    ).Value.astype(object).unstack().loc[[1,2,3,4,5], 'a']
)

(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

---

```
tuple(df.set_index(
        ['No', 'Sim']
    ).Value.astype(object).unstack().loc[[1,2,3,4,5], 'b']
)

(7, 8, 9, None, 10)
```